# Problem with IE6 css

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

I have a problem with IE6 and jquery slider.
Please click on the following link than click on the button "dodaj u košaricu" on the right bottom side. After that click on the "košarica" tab and try to move slider up and down.
Some of the elements stay like they have position fixed.

[link text](http://www.fckids.hr/kolekcija.php?action=no&type=single&nav=2&articleId=304)

In IE6 all of the elements except table and text stay fixed and in IE7 only the horizontal slider, in FF everything is OK.

Comment: You would definitely have more success, if you post your code

Comment: ...or if the link worked

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm generally against "you don't want to do *that*, you want to do *this*" answers, I'll have to make an exception in this case.

Interface elements (scrollbars, buttons, sliders etc.) have either an intended purpose, or a purpose accepted by convention. If you adhere to the conventions you'll make things easier for your users and less complicated for yourself.

In this case, you are using a slider to select the quantity of an item to be purchased. That is, you want the user to specify a discrete integer value.

A slider is great for (pseudo)analogue values such as volume. In such cases the user knows there's a lower bound (no sound) and an upper bound (lots of sound) but won't generally be able to dictate any desired level in-between. The user won't think in the concept of +1 or -1 volume but will think in terms of 'a little more' or 'a little less'.

For discrete values, a slider is appropriate for the selection of one value out of a pre-defined set:

[image]

A slider is not the best choice for selecting an unbounded integer value. Certainly the user can assume the left-most position to be zero, but what does the right-most position indicate? Does the slider go from *zero* to *all*? What is *all*?

Aside from the choice of value being selected with the slider being unclear, users will not expect a slider to be used for this purpose.

You should really simplify the interface to benefit the users and yourself.

A standard text input will suffice. People know what these do, will understand the purpose of a text input in a field marked 'quantity' (ah - I type in the number I want) and will not be confused.

This will greatly simplify the development and maintenance process for yourself. How long will it take to implement a text input compared to a slider? What can go wrong with a standard text input? Probably nothing. What can go wrong with a custom slider? Well, as we can see various things can do wrong depending on the browser.

From a "wow - it works!" perspective a slider can seem cool, but users won't care (they're very fickle creatures). The user will not think "a slider - how cool is that, I must shop here again". The user will think "this site won't even let me select the quantity - I'll not shop here at all".

Just keep it simple.

Comment: well, I do not agree with you, while I know what you mean, I think that slider in this type is a very good choice cause values in the slider are always predefined, from 0 to max available, and max is never more than a 100, so in this terms it gives another alternative to input box which is also here for the user. By using a slider, user does not need to use a keyboard and thus I think it simplifies ordering.